# Заполнение массива из файла

Tags: java

Не могу понять как.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("output"), Charset.defaultCharset());  - так считывает.

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output");
            out.println(Arrays.toString(fulling));
            out.close();- так записывает
```

Проблема в том, что считывает он построчно, а запись такого вида [1,2,3,4,5,6,] как этот кусок в квадратных скобках воткнуть в массив. Чувствую что это элементарно, но не доходит .... до меня ....

Comment: .substring()  и .split() вам в помощь

Comment: String[] split = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,]".split("]|,|\\["); - например, сплит с решуляркой

Comment: Спасибо :) Разобрался